# How to get only some digits in a number value in roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am still working on the project that I made, the computer PIN cracking thing. And I want to make that when somebody click on a hint button, it will display the 1/4 of the password, the other will remains "*". But I can't even think of something to do!

I think the math element can help me with this, but I can't understand what does what, so I can't write anything out, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `string` methods can help out...

```
> function click(pin)
>> local rnd = math.random(#pin)
>> local dig = pin:sub(rnd, rnd)
>> return(pin:gsub('.', function(m) if m == dig then return(m) else return('*') end end))
>> end
> pin=1234567890
> click(tostring(pin))
*******8**
> click(tostring(pin))
*****6****
> click(tostring(pin))
********9*
> click(tostring(pin))
****5*****
```

1. Pick a random char/digit from `pin` (`dig = pin:sub(rnd, rnd)`)
2. Return what match (`m == dig`) at its position the rest fill out with `*`

Comment: Can you point out what this script is doing? I don't know what is it doing, it is hard to make it more helpful and solve my problem.